# IVY/JAR ERROR - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row

Tags: java, apache, jar, apache-poi, ivy

Hi I know this question has been asked multiple times but I have tried all of those suggested!

My code works perfectly fine in Eclipse however I want to build jar and run through command line in Unix.

In my dependent ivy.xml I have listed my dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
              <dependency org="org.apache.xmlbeans" name="xmlbeans" rev="2.6.0"/>
              <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi" rev="3.11" conf="default" /> 
              <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi-ooxml" rev="3.11" conf="default" />
              <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi-ooxml-schemas" rev="3.11" conf="default" />
    </dependencies>
```

But when I execute my jar, I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row

I know you need to have poi-ooxml for ss, however, I have referenced that in my ivy dependencies.

Why am I still getting this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you making sure you include the dependencies on *both* the Compile Time *and* runtime classpaths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your jar is missing a classpath in it's manifest. Try the following:

```
<target name="build" depends="test" description="Create executable jar archive">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${jar.file}">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.main.class}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Notes:

- The ivy **retrieve** task is used to place the dependencies into the distribution directory alongside the jar being built
- The **manifestclasspath** task is a useful trick for creating the correct relative paths for a possibly long list of dependencies

Comment: I finally figured it out, my work's default version was 3.6 (really old) whereas I was using a newer one which apparently doesn't work in our environment.

Comment: @anirana93 Ok... but the whole point of using ivy to manage your dependencies is to make your build independent of the environment it runs upon (I call this the "magic build server" problem). Managing the classpath also needs to be done at runtime. That is why in the example above I have outlined how ivy can be used to setup the correct classpath within the jar you're building. Just run the command "java -jar myapp.jar"